# What does exactly Spring Configuration mean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I talking about the concept rather than @Configuration annotation and I could not find any clear definition of it in the official documentation. What do we mean by Spring "configuration" ?

- Is it defining the beans in IoC container?
- Is it glueing different Spring components and/or open source libraries together?
- Is it changing web-server settings in case of Spring Boot?
- Is it all of above? or even more?

Comment: spring has been around for a long while. what exactly it means has ebbed and flowed. once it was all xml definitions with J2EE utilities but is now more annotations and conventions. there were a couple of java community process JSRs that attempted to make what spring does a standard. yet at this point “spring is spring”. competing frameworks have a more focused feature set but have no significant market share when looking to hire developers. IMHO the core patterns of dependency injection, inversion of control, along with many ways to "wire" (aka configure) you application, may describe it.

Comment: Just the first. The rest are corollary to that. In Spring everything is a bean TM so definining beans is the core mechanic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Spring Framework Reference - version 5.1.3.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/index.html):

> [**1.2.1. Configuration Metadata**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-metadata)
>
> ... the Spring IoC container consumes a form of configuration
>   metadata. This configuration metadata represents how you, as an
>   application developer, ***tell the Spring container to instantiate,
>   configure, and assemble the objects in your application.***
>
> ...
>
> ***Spring configuration consists of at least one and typically more than
>   one bean definition that the container must manage.*** XML-based
>   configuration metadata configures these beans as  elements
>   inside a top-level  element. Java configuration typically uses
>   @Bean-annotated methods within a @Configuration class.

So,

> - Is it defining the beans in IoC container?

We can say **`Yes`** to that.